# Google Sheets - Sum of vlookup in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

Hitting a brainfreeze, can't figure it out.

Problem:

```
I can't figure out how to add together Table#1 Sam WC 
results as a nice table for Table#2. What I need is the results in Table#2.
```

Table #1:

```
| Unique      | Worker | Object   | Time |
|-------------|--------|----------|------|
| Sam WC      | Sam    | WC       | 1.0  |
| Ian WC      | Ian    | WC       | 1.0  |
| Sam WC      | Sam    | WC       | 2.0  | 
| Sam Kitchen | Sam    | Kitchen  | 4.0  | 
| Ian Kitchen | Ian    | Kitchen  | 4.0  |
```

Table #2:

```
| Object      | Sam    | Ian   |
|-------------|--------|-------|
| WC          | 3.0    | 1.0   |
| Kitchen     | 4.0    | 4.0   |
```

My solution so far:

```
I used VLOOKUP, "Unique" field and referred to Time

Only problem it obviously displayed only one result and 
didn't add Sam WC total time together. So instead of 3.0 I saw 1.0.
```

My formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Table#2 Sam+WC,Table#1,4,FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

As always as soon as you post help you figure it out yourself. :/

Apparently there is a nifty formula for exactly this.

SUMIF allowed me to pick a range (so my unique ID column) , then pick a criteria (my single Unique ID) , and then pick the range of numbers to count the SUM.